# How do I create a feature using coordinates in a certain format?

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates

I have been provided with the geometry and spatial reference of a number of features in this format:

"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}

**Geometry**
[[[285518.2,6943346.1],[289053.5,6944081.2],[289053.5,6944081.2],[289310.1,6944134.5],[302839.3,6946932.1],[303901.1,6947150.7],[303961.8,6947164.1],[304021.6,6947181.4],[304080.2,6947202.4],[304137.4,6947227.1],[304192.9,6947255.2],[304246.5,6947286.9],[304298,6947321.8],[304347.3,6947360],[304394,6947401.1],[304438.1,6947445.1],[304479.4,6947491.8],[304517.6,6947541],[304552.7,6947592.5],[304584.5,6947646.1],[304612.9,6947701.7],[304637.7,6947758.8],[304658.9,6947817.5],[304676.4,6947877.3],[304690.1,6947938.2],[304700,6947999.8],[304706,6948061.9],[304707.1,6948095.2],[304707.1,6948116.2].....

Is there is a simple way to draw this feature in Arc or to format the coords into a classic X&Y spreadsheet?

Comment: This looks like some bits and pieces of a geojson file.  Can you post everything you have and not just a portion?  If this is all you have did you try to bring it into a text editor and build a comma delimited text file from it?  Without improving your post with some demonstrated effort on your part, and a more focused question, your post will be closed by the administrators.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers "wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857 indicate this is the WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere projection an article is found [here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013950).

Below is an example of taking part of your list of coordinates and creating a geometry object from it and then writing it to an in-memory featureclass. This gives you the salient steps for which you need only wrap up in a loop.

```py
coordList = [[285518.2,6943346.1],[289053.5,6944081.2],[289053.5,6944081.2],[289310.1,6944134.5],[302839.3,6946932.1],[303901.1,6947150.7],[303961.8,6947164.1],[304021.6,6947181.4],[304080.2,6947202.4],[304137.4,6947227.1],[304192.9,6947255.2],[304246.5,6947286.9],[304298,6947321.8]]
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in coordList]),sr)
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(polyline,"memory/test")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a geometry feature, based on some [WKID](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-SpatialReference.html#wkid) (well-known ID), with the [arcgis.geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html#) module. But for that, you need to install the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-older-versions/) for your ArcGIS Pro.

Here is the patterna to use Geometry (in your case, considering the first nine features) :

```
geom = Geometry({
    "features" : [[[285518.2,6943346.1],[289053.5,6944081.2],[289053.5,6944081.2],
    [289310.1,6944134.5],[302839.3,6946932.1],[303901.1,6947150.7],
    [303961.8,6947164.1],[304021.6,6947181.4],[304080.2,6947202.4]]],
    "spatialReference" : {"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}
                })
```

**Note** : The [Geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html?highlight=point#geometry) constructor is able to figure out the type of geometry.